What is the optical activity of EDTA-Zinc(II) ion?

In this compound, the ligand EDTA is apparently optically active according to my textbook.
But I have found that in similar compounds like $\ce{[Co(EDTA)]-}$ do not exhibit optical isomerism
as in the ligand donor atoms are similar and do not have chiral centres.
but there are other complexes $\ce{[Pd(EDTA)]^2-}$ where EDTA acts like an tetradentate ligand and due to this it can show optical activity.
So, is it the same thing happening in $\ce{[Zn(EDTA)]^2-}$ or is something different altogether also could someone explain why tetradentate EDTA shows optical activity in $\ce{[Pd(EDTA)]^2-}$

The ligand is never optically active, but ion may be a chiral center.

Chiral centres are not much of a thing. Your left hand is left, and your right hand is right; where is their chiral center?

Oh ok so it is safe to assume that [Zn(edta)]2- is tetradentate not hexadentate could you please explain why in tetradentate state it is optical active and how can we know that it's tetradentate in a certain complex.

EDTA is not chiral, but its arrangement makes the complex chiral by creating a stereocenter around the zinc. To get the coordination geometry shown the $\ce{CH2CO2^-}$ groups are on opposite sides of the EDTA portion of the ligand, and this prevents the existence of a mirror plane or a center of symmetry.

Can you separate the racemic mixture? If not, there would not be any measurable optical activity.

I wiuld not know. This is why I said "chiral". Sepqlarating tge racemic mixture may well require optically active media.
